# connection to MySql database on host

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a problem regarding connecting to my database that is located on my website host server. I have watched few tutorials, took a look on few articles here on stack overflow and read official mysql documentation, and i steel can't connect to it thru my c# console app. This is my code:

```
string connstring = string.Format("Server=www.vm-consult.com; Database=vmconsul_sitedatabase; Uid=vmconsul_mijovicpetar; Pwd=mypassword");
MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection();
connection.ConnectionString = connstring;

connection.Open();
```

I have also went to c panel in remote MySQL tab and set "%" to my remote sql hosts.

All the parameters for con string are correct. In server in connection string I also tried to set IP address, did not change anything.

This is exception I get(on the last line: connection.open()):

> Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.

Any suggestions appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: some hosts don't allow % in the whitelist. you might need to be more specific. also, stuff may or may not need to be restarted on the server.

Comment: @Pamblam I have edited my post. I added in which line exception is being thrown. this is what is written in c panel: Host (% wildcard is allowed). I also tried to add my IP address instead of %, but had no success either. Is there any more information you need for a possible answer? Thanks for commenting.

Comment: I seriously doubt that the database runs on the front-end web server itself, using the public IP and name. If it did, I'd drop the host provider **immediatelly*. What's your database server's name? If it runs on the same machine as your website, why don't you use `127.0.0.1`? If it runs on a different machine, you have to find the name/IP address of that machine

Comment: i've had this problem in cpanel before. on shared hosting it has sometimes taken up to a full day for these changes to propagate. in the past i've always solved this problem by speaking with tech support at the host.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Is tehre a way to find out what is that machine name other then contacting my host?

Comment: Only *they* can tell you how to connect to the database. Didn't they do that? Doesn't cpanel show that you have a MySql database or what the connection string is?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes i can see my database but not the connection string.

Answer (score 0):

Check connectivity with

```
telnet www.vm-consult.com 3306
```

Comment: Where should I type that line?

Comment: Open a command prompt and enter the line. You might have to install telnet on your machine (https://www.rootusers.com/how-to-enable-the-telnet-client-in-windows-10/)

Answer (score 0):

I needed to contact my host provider to enable external connection to the database. Thanks everybody.